# Android How to get List of uninstalled apps from device

Tags: android

In my use case i want to access list of all uninstalled from device.

i tried this-

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> applications = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
  Log.d("pkg inofo->", appInfo.packageName);
```

but it is not working for me it is not return list of uninstalled app.

so my question is what is wrong with this code or any other approach to get list of uninstalled apps.

Comment: There is no method in the PackageManager for uninstalled apps.

Comment: The `GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES` flag does not do what you think it does. Please read the documentation for it more carefully.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. i have read document it says "Flag parameter to retrieve some information about all applications (even uninstalled ones) which have data directories." but not clear what information i can retrive of unintalled apps.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no way to get uninstalled apps.**

But you can get list of uninstalled application after your app is installed.
You need to use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>`, whenever any application is removed you can store it in your DB and get the list of uninstalled apps.